# Multiple instances of the same function asynchronously in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have a little script that does a few simple tasks. Running Python 3.7.

One of the tasks has to merge some files together which can be a little time consuming.

It loops through multiple directories, then each directory gets passed to the function. The function just loops through the files and merges them.

Instead of waiting for it to finish one directory, then onto the next one, then wait, then onto the next one, etc...

I'd like to utilize the horsepower/cores/threads to have the script merging the PDF's in multiple directories at once, together, which should shave time.

I've got something like this:

```
if multi_directories:
    if os.path.isdir('merged'):
        pass
    else:
        os.makedirs('merged')
    for directory in multi_directories:
        merge_pdfs(directory)
```

My merge PDF function looks like this:

```
def merge_pdfs(directory):
    root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    merged_dir_location = os.path.join(root_dir, 'merged')
    dir_title = directory.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    file_list = [file for file in os.listdir(directory)]
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for pdf in file_list:
        file_to_open = os.path.join(directory, pdf)
        merger.append(open(file_to_open, 'rb'))
        file_to_save = os.path.join(
            merged_dir_location,
            dir_title+"-merged.pdf"
        )
    with open(file_to_save, "wb") as fout:
        merger.write(fout)
    return True
```

This works great - but `merge_pdfs` runs slow in some instances where there are a high number of PDF's in the directory.

Essentially - I want to be a be able to loop through `multi_directories` and create a new thread or process for each directory and merge the PDF's at the same time.

I've looked at `asyncio`, `multithreading` and a wealth of little snippets here and there but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: `mutliprocessing.Pool` would probably be the way to go here. Create a pool that executes the merger, then use its apply function to iterate over the list of directories.

Comment: @torek - Are there some examples of that somewhere?

Comment: Probably lots here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
n_processes = 2
...
if multi_directories:
    if os.path.isdir('merged'):
        pass
    else:
        os.makedirs('merged')
    pool = Pool(n_processes)
    pool.map(merge_pdfs, multi_directories)
```

It should help if the bottleneck is CPU usage. But it may make things even worse if the bottleneck is HDD, cause reading several files in parallel from one physical HDD is usually slower then reading them consecutively. Try it with different values of *n_processes*.

BTW, to make list from iterable use *list()*: `file_list = list(os.listdir(directory))`. And since *listdir()* returns *List*, you can just write `file_list = os.listdir(directory)`

Comment: This worked a treat - and on some of my bigger pdf sets dropped the time this process took *considerably* (multiple minutes)! Thanks for the explanations and the tweaks in other areas! Very appreciated.